# How to open Parent View with selected partial from _Layout in MVC using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to open Parent View with selected partial from `_Layout.cshtml` in MVC using JQuery.

Currently, control does not hit the `ActionResult A`. Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Controller

```
  public ActionResult A(string str)
    {
        switch (str)
        {
            case "Ab":
                return PartialView("_Ab");

            case "Ts":
                return PartialView("_Ts");
        }
       return View();
    }
```

Parent View

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" id="Ab"><a href="#">Ab</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item" id="Ts"><a href="#">Ts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" id="partial"> 
</div>
```

_Layout

```
 <footer>  
    <div class="pull-right">
        <p><a id="Ab" class="AbTs" href="#">Ab</a>|<a id="Ts" class="AbTs" href="#"> Ts</a></p>
    </div>     
</footer>
```

Script

```
   $('.AbTs').click(function () {
        debugger;
         var str = this.id;
         var id= '@Url.Action("A", "Home")?str=' + str;
            id = encodeURI(id);         
            $('#partial').load(id);
        });
```

Comment: Is your debugger being hit? Is request being made in dev tools network? What is it's status?

Comment: @charlietfl, Yes it hits the debugger. If you see in `<footer>` section then you can find `AbTs`

Comment: Yes I missed that class and removed that part of comment. What about request itself in dev tools network?

Comment: What would `var str = this.str;` return? What value are you wanting to passing to the method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry Stephen. It should be `var str = this.id` and it returns id of particular link.

Comment: I want to pass the this value in my controller and want to display both parent view along with selected partial.

Comment: What do you mean _display both parent view along with selected partial_? (you can only return 1 view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want to display the parent view and  `<div class="col-md-8" id="partial">` also.

Comment: But you are already in the parent view page? Its not clear what your issue is

Comment: @StephenMuecke, No I am not in the parent View. When the project loads, it loads the home page and there is no link for my parent view. It all should load when in footer link is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171888/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user9895).